# Vim: inserting at the end of the line

Tags: vim, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a key to **insert** something at the end of the line in Vim? It would be similar to `A`, except it would insert before the last character, not after it.

A use case is for example in Python:

```
if ((a and b) or c:
```

and you want to insert the missing parenthesis before the colon. There are similar use cases in C-syntax languages when you want to insert something before the semi-colon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To insert before the last character, use `$i`.  This isn't a common enough case to warrant a single-key command, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built-in command that uses one single keystroke, but If you use it often consider creating a map:

```
nnoremap Q $i
```

Alternatively you can use `A<left>` in your map to achieve the same effect.